# how to redirect page in server side of spring MVC with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

Angular js is a single page web application so that the spring controller modelAndView method is not redirecting. how we redirect the spring controller
this is spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/toostudentregister/{eventid}")
    public String studentregister(@PathVariable int eventid, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session)
    {
        System.out.print("passing "+eventid);
        session.setAttribute("eventid",eventid);
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
```

this is angular js code

```
 $scope.goid = function(eventid)
     {
         alert(eventid);
         $scope.userss = $resource('toostudentregister/'+eventid).query(function(data){return data;})   
};
```